# Keep thread synchronized across multiple devices (ejabberd/conversations)

Tags: synchronization, ejabberd

I want to use two different client devices with the same jabber ID, and I want the message thread to appear the same to both of them, even if one of the clients is offline for a period of time. Both clients run Conversations and the server is ejabberd 21.12.

The both mod_carboncopy (XEP-0208) and mod_mam are activated in ejabberd.yml.

mod_mam is activated as follows:

```
mod_mam:
    db_type: sql
    access_preferences: none
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: never
```

The behavior observed is:

- Messages SENT to the account go to both clients if they are both online.
- If only one client is online, messages SENT to the account to the online client. The second client does not get these messages when it comes online.
- Messages SENT from either client appear in both clients' threads (I believe that this is the action of mod_carboncopy).

Desired behavior:

- Messages sent to the account go to both clients. If one is online, it gets the message. The second client gets the message when it comes online later.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself: change "default: never" to "default: always" under mod_mam in ejabberd.yml.

I would still like a way to control how long the message archive is kept.